# Create a menubar for GTK 2.24 and GTK 3 and GTK 4

Tags: c, gtk3, gtk2, gtk4

GTK 4 will remove [GtkMenu, GtkMenuBar and GtkMenuItem](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/unstable/ch32s02.html#id-1.6.4.4.63). Why not, but, is there a **common way** to create a classic menubar for [GTK 2.24](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/) and [GTK 3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.24/) and [GTK 4](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/4.0/) in C?

An example:

[image: classic edit menu]

Comment: Yes, use GtkPopoverMenu. GTK2 is out.

Comment: I found another way, for info, read [create_traditional_menubar](https://github.com/luigifab/awf-extended/blob/35e433bd5d312b0af379729278bdd0a090f22cb5/src/awf.c#L2057).